# AS3: waiting for multiple loaders to complete

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have an arbitrary number of images I want to load.  I want to load them, wait until I get an Event.INIT for each, and only then proceed with the rest of the program.

I know I can do that by having an Event.INIT listener update and check some count variable, but is that the standard approach?  Is there a more elegant or AS-specific way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use LoaderMax, developed by greensock (the developer of TweenMax).

http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/

You can create a loading group and wait for the complete event for that group. The code is documented very well.

Here is a quick mockup of code to give you an idea about what you can expect:

```
mediaLoader = new LoaderMax( { name:"mediaLoader" } );
mediaLoader.addEventListener(LoaderEvent.PROGRESS, onMediaLoadProgress);
mediaLoader.addEventListener(LoaderEvent.COMPLETE, onMediaLoadComplete);
mediaLoader.addEventListener(LoaderEvent.ERROR, onMediaLoadError);

for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    mediaLoader.append(LoaderMax.parse("image_" + i + ".jpg", { estimatedBytes: 100000 }));
}
```

It also gives you specialized loaders for images, video, sound, etc. You can use them to your advantage, or just treat them transparently.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about loading groups.

Answer (score 2):

You could store every loader in an array and remove them when they dispatch INIT

```
private function onInit(e:Event):void
{
  var loader:Loader = (e.currentTarget as LoaderInfo).loader;
  _loaders.splice(_loaders.indexOf(loader), 1);
  if (_loaders.length == 0)
    //do something
}
```

You could also just use a count variable as you say. This is ok since a loader won't dispatch INIT twice. But you will have to remove the loader from the array or decrease your counter on the error events as well.

Comment: That makes sense.  I think I need to move the loader.content into Sprites anyway, in which case I should probably get rid of the loaders to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

There's no 'standard approach'. You have to implement it by your own with some counter as @Kodiak said.

But take a look at [LoaderMax](http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/) library if you need something more complex. You can set 'maxConnections' parameter to determine how many stuffs it is loading at one time.