# In flash how to load several swfs and make them start together?

Tags: flash

Let's assume that I can't script the loaded swf, nor can the loaded one script the loader swf.

I was attempting to set frame rate to 0, and wait after all swfs are loaded, and set frame rate back. But I found when I set the frame rate to 0, I could not receive the complete event! And it's weird that i can still receive UI events...

Is there a way to load several swfs and start them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Timers don't rely on frame. I can check loader's contentLoaderInfo manually during timer event.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop each SWF individually when they are loaded (you can listen the contentLoaderInfo of a Loader for Event.COMPLETE) and by checking a counter, start all of them when they all finish loading. You can store each loaded SWF in an array meanwhile.

Also, you might want to check this: [AS3: waiting for multiple loaders to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239278/as3-waiting-for-multiple-loaders-to-complete)

Comment: The loader is written in AS3, but the loaded swf may be written in AS2. I didn't find a stop() method for AS2/1 movieclip. And even if I stop a movieclip, its child is still playing, just the current frame won't advance.

Comment: AS2 would change everything. If you could somehow guarantee that everything that is loaded would be AS3, you could do something along the lines of http://www.unfocus.com/2009/12/07/stop-all-child-movieclips-in-flash-with-actionscript-3-0/

Comment: With that said, the only solution I can think of is that loading each SWF and removing them as soon as they are loaded. Then you could load them again (from the cache) and start the playback when they are loaded again.

Comment: To make it fast, I can use loadBytes(). But loadBytes() is asynchronous, too. Is there some other event mechanism like UI event that don't rely on frame but can be triggered automatically. So I can check the state of the loader actively?